# Native Federation Angular - Can I define an Angular library as a federated module?

Tags: angular, micro-frontend, esbuild

I'm developing an frontend app which consists of several micro-frontends. The project is based on the new angular v17. Additionally, the app's been designed to be a plugin-based system, therefore the need of using runtime integration as basis. As Angular is moving away from **webpack** to **esbuild** from v17, I have no choice but using native-federation.

I've done in the past some runtime-integrations of multiple apps into a shell container using native-federation and it worked well. Now, I've received a **requirement** stating that my federated modules should be Angular libraries as well. Those libraries in general aim to export some services and UI components, which eventually are going to be used by my shell app.

So I went to my library workspace and tried to define it as remote as I'd usually do. Then, I got the following error:

```
The project doesn't have a build or serve target in angular.json!
```

As far as I understand, the idea of native-federation helps loading **EcmaScript** modules from separately **compiled** and **deployed** apps (remotes). My library exposes ES modules. Of course, I cannot run the library without providing any app context. So would it mean that only Angular apps can be federated modules? What am I missing?

Here some relevant links for the integration:

1. [native-federation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-architects/native-federation)

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks in advance